# Why function can change `const char * & value`?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants

This is an example of a function taking `const char * &` as a parameter.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char test[] = "Test";

void func(const char * & str)
{
    str = &test[0];
}

int main() {
    const char * mytest;

    func(mytest);

    cout << mytest << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Why does this work? (http://ideone.com/7NwmYd)

What `const` means here? Why `func()` can change `str` given to this function?

Upd. It's a newbie question, please not minus it.

Comment: Read it right to left: it's taking a reference to a pointer to a constant character.

Comment: Is [this](http://ideone.com/gtydf4) what you were thinking?

Comment: Have marked it as a dupe (I'm assuming the confusion is around the `const`, not the `&`...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cost refers to the portion of the declaration immediately to its left, except in the special case that const is first, in which case immediately to its right:

```
const char * &  // the char is const, the * is not
char const * &  // the char is const, the * is not
char * const &  // the * is const, the char is not
char const * const &  // the char and * are both const
```

You had a non const pointer to a const char and modified the pointer (not the char) so there was nothing for the compiler to complain about.